# Type conversion in C# for SQL data

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a `DataTable` which is filled from a SQL database. Values are returned as object type (also the `Calculate` function returns object as well for some reason), so I need to convert them to proper type. It makes the code so complicated.

Like this:

```
 double value;

 foreach (DataRow row in sampleDataTable.Rows)
 {
     value +=  (double)Global.Calculate(Convert.ToDouble(Global.dbNullCheck(row["value1"], 0)) / Convert.ToDouble(row["value2"]), 2);
 }
```

I can write above code as:

```
 double sum;
 double value1;
 double value2;

 foreach (DataRow row in sampleDataTable.Rows)
 {
     value1 = Convert.ToDouble(Global.dbNullCheck(row["value1"], 0);
     value2 = Convert.ToDouble(row["value2"]);
     sum +=  (double)Global.Calculate(value1 / value2, 2);
 }
```

But of course, it is still not clear and I am doing something wrong. I need to check all values if they are `DBNull` and after that I need to convert them. Any ideas how can I improve this type of code? It's all around my code :)

Is there a good way to handle SQL data?

Comment: This is not related to the <sql> language. Perhaps you should have added <sql-server> tag instead?

Comment: Use : foreach (DataRow row in sampleDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<object>("value1") == DBNull.Value))

Comment: The problem starts presumably in not using something strongly typed in the first place. You are now so far down the road of weakly typed things that its hard to come up with a generic easy solution now. Most ORMs or any type of mapper it could be handled in a central place but after that you would not need to fiddle with those details anymore.

Comment: @Ralf By weakly typed you mean lots of return types with object? Isn't C# is already strongly typed language? I didn't use ORM before, is it the solution for this type of cases?

Comment: Your code is fine.  All you variable have types.

Comment: Weakly typed maybe the wrong wording here. I meant that you used a type that represent any data coming from the database. Simple DataRows and DataTables. So you need to code the way you do and use literals for column names and need to cast/convert to the type that its actually meant. But if you had a design that directly creates a "hard typed" class. With simple properties having correct naming and correct datatypes you would not have the problems you face here because the framework used would have solved it for you. That could be an ORM or just a Typed Dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Don't think in terms of "convert". These objects are **already** the types you want; it's just the ADO.Net library can't know in advance what type to use. So instead of a conversion, which can be relatively slow, you need a **cast**.

Additionally, in general you don't want to think initially in terms of individual columns. Instead, define a `class` object to represent each row. Then create a function that accepts a `DataRow` as an argument and returns an instance of this new class as a result. This function *will* need to know what to do with individual columns, but the larger `foreach` loop (or similar) should just be calling this function.